# Notification service extension starting on iPhone/iPad but not on M1 Mac

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, apple-m1

I am developing an iOS app that uses a notification service extension (NSE) to format the remote notifications obtained from Apple Push Notification Service.

When I install the app on an iPad or an iPhone, the remote notifications are correctly formatted via the extension before they are displayed to the user.

However, when I install the app on a Mac with an M1 Silicon chip, remote notifications are not re-formatted, but are displayed in raw format.

I have used the *console* to try to trace what is going on with the extension on the Mac. I see no occurrence of a running NSE. Rather, I see multiple messages like these:

> failed to fetch /Applications/My.app/Wrapper/My.app/PlugIns/NotificationServiceExtension.appex/_CodeSignature/CodeRequirements-2 error=-10

When I run `pluginkit --match` in the *Terminal*, the extension is listed, but there is no +/- sign indicating whether the extension is enabled or disabled.

Looking in *System Preferences*, *Extensions* tab, the extension is not listed in the *Added extensions* list. (Not sure if it should be, but nevertheless it isn't.)

Is there some configuration step I am missing to enable the notification service extension on the M1 Mac, or does not iOS developed NSEs run on M1 Macs?

Comment: As it turned out, the problem appear to be that my extension initially was "too heavy". After stripping it from all third-party package references, I was finally able to build and run it on M1 Mac as well.

Comment: It is strange that it was too heavy if it worked on iPhone. I can't start the same. pluginkit --match shows all iOS extensions with ! sign and can't find, but they are in the Wrapper/App/Plugins